# Can we enforce timeout for java interface implementation?

Tags: java

I'm working on a game server based in java.  My design on the server side is as follows.
The RuleEnforcer is passed in a list of IPlayers, and it initiates communication with the players.  IPlayers is an interface, and i imagine implementing a dummy Player for testing purpose, a "smart" player, and also a player that eventually interacts with a remote client UI interface.  In RuleEnforcer when player methods are called, it needs to ensure that the method returns (on time). eg:

```
for(player : players) {
    player.giveAcard(card);
}
```

giveACard has no return type, and the each player needs to just save the card and return immediately. But if a player implementation sleeps on the method call, the game is stuck.
How do I account for that in my code ? One approach I can think of is to call player interactions in a different thread, and use wait.  Is there any design that is applicable to this scenario, or is my approach wrong ?

Comment: are you running it in a thread or in main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can create by this way.
create a constructor

```
SimpleTimeLimiter()
```

Constructs a TimeLimiter instance using a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` to execute proxied method calls.
method detail with new proxy....

```
public <T> T newProxy(T target,
             Class<T> interfaceType,
             long timeoutDuration,
             TimeUnit timeoutUnit)
```

then call with timeout...

```
callWithTimeout
public <T> T callWithTimeout(Callable<T> callable,
                    long timeoutDuration,
                    TimeUnit timeoutUnit,
                    boolean amInterruptible)
```

for reference use...new proxy..

```
public <T> T newProxy(T target,
             Class<T> interfaceType,
             long timeoutDuration,
             TimeUnit timeoutUnit)
```

Comment: thank you.  That seems to have been written for exactly that purpose. guava and their nifty little solutions :)